# Win form application start up error

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-deployment

Hi I have developed a application using C# and .Net Framework 3.5 in VS 2010.

When I install it on my system it works perfect but when I install it on client system it giving me below error.

Additional:
I have installed all prerequisites on client system. Configured the database and all as it requires.

[image: Error Message]

What would be the issue?

Comment: What are the differences between the machines?

Comment: @Tico My development and testing system having Windows 7 and client system is server system having Windows XP

Comment: .NET Framework is up to date? x86 vs x64? Admin rights? Think about all your references as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be framework problem I think. check framework version by below,

```
dir %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v*

dir %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v* /O:-N /B
```